# XSLT - Split the tag into group of 2 tags

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to perform an XSL transformation on the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:CommissionEvents xmlns="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes" xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager">

<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121897883089643</Serial>
        </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121903131477120</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
         <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)189513222896(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121189513222896</Serial>
            </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
         <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)468091235492(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121468091235492</Serial>
            </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)704297270475(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121704297270475</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">013035513513201221389170110454</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)724826376009(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">013035513513201221724826376009</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)">00003551350000000907</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
<ns2:CommissionEvent>
       <NumberList>
        <Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000235" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)">00003551350000000235</Serial>
       </NumberList>
</ns2:CommissionEvent>
</ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

Below is the attempt I made but did not get expected output--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes"
xmlns:ns0="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns2:CommissionEvents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="ns2:CommissionEvent" group-by="NumberList/Serial/concat(@filterValue, '|', @format)">
            <ns2:CommissionEvent>
                <ns0:NumberList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <ns0:Serial> 
                            <xsl:copy-of select="NumberList/Serial/(@*|text())"/>
                        </ns0:Serial> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:NumberList>
            </ns2:CommissionEvent> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output from above xslt --

```
<ns2:CommissionEvents>              
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)189513222896(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)468091235492(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)704297270475(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)724826376009(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
            <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000235" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is something like the below. I tried for each loop grouping based on @filterValue and @format. Could someone help me achieving this using xslt 2.0

```
<ns2:CommissionEvents>              
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)189513222896(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)468091235492(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)704297270475(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)724826376009(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
            <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000235" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

Comment: Could someone please look into this and help.

Comment: Try to shorten the sample data to a minimum to demonstrate the problem. I am afraid if you expect us to identify what you want with data like `<ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)189513222896(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />` it will be very hard for us to distinguish values. Are these `barcodeContent` attributes, for instance, of any relevance to the grouping problem? If not, cut them. Also show the wrong result you got and explain which part is wrong.

Comment: With above approach am getting output with set of three <ns2:CommissionEvent>. I want to split 1st set of <ns2:CommissionEvent> into 2. Please suggest the approach. Let me if its clear or still need some more info.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have updated the question as well for more clarity. Could you please check and help on this.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Is that grouping you do part of your requirement or just the code you got on a previous answer? What does split into 2 mean exactly, given that one of your result elements has three and not two `Serial` elements?

Comment: yes Martin, your last statement is what I need actually. If you notice the current output I have mentioned above, 1st <ns2:CommissionEvent> has 5 <ns0:Serial>. I want to split <ns2:CommissionEvent> into group of 2. Rest of the output is ok.